# Cython does not build .so file

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying `cython` for the first time. Here is what I have.

**setup.py**

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
setup(ext_modules = cythonize('example123.pyx'))
```

**example123.pyx**

```
def say_hello(name):
    print(f"Hello {name}")
```

After `setup.py build_ext --inplace` I only see `example123.c` in the folder, no other files created. Searching through all the files didn't provide any results. As far as I know, a `.so` or `.pyd` file must have appeared to import into a python script. What may be the problem?

**My specs:** *Windows 7 x64*, *gcc mingw64*, *python 3.8*, *cython 0.29.24*

Comment: You need to use `Extension` from either `setuptools` or `distutils`

Comment: @Fiver couldn't you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: The accepted answer here is a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323474/distutils-core-vs-setuptools-with-c-extension

Comment: There is normally a log printed to stdout, telling you what is going on/wrong. There must be an error, e.g. no compiler installed/found.

Comment: @Fiver, OP’s setup file is straight from cython documentation - this not the problem: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html

Comment: @ead yes and that's embarassing

Comment: The changing of directories may be the issue

Comment: @Fiver it is not, I removed it and checked

Comment: I don't think mingw64 is supported/working on any recent version of Python (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) (unless you've built a special version of Python itself with that compiler_. I'd still expect to see an error output though

Comment: @DavidW There is no any error in the output, everything is as if the program has terminated successfully

Comment: Where are you running `setup.py build_ext --inplace`? I'd expect it to produce some output (whether it's running successfully or not). However, the main point I was making is that I don't think Mingw64 will work at all

Comment: I have a similar problem however I can see a file .pyd but not the .so. Any suggestions? @DavidW even with mingw32 it still the same output

Comment: @sos I don't know why you think I have an answer. I was saying "don't use this". I also was not advising that mingw32 worked!

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654722/how-to-create-c-extension-embed-python-with-mingw-w64-on-windows though

Answer (score 1):

remove `__init__.py` in the current folder if having any